# What's wrong with my user mapping in pg_ident?

Tags: postgresql, users

I have successfully setup certificate based authentication in postgresql-11. Now I want to do a user mapping:

pg_ident.conf

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
mymap /^(.*)\.testnet\.com$    \1
```

pg_hba.conf

```
hostssl all all all cert map=mymap
```

Then I signed a certificate with CN `user1.testnet.com`, and it won't match the existing `user`:

```
2022-04-30 15:17:27.036 CST [29520] LOG:  no match in usermap "mymap" for user "user1.testnet.com" authenticated as "user1.testnet.com"
2022-04-30 15:17:27.036 CST [29520] FATAL:  certificate authentication failed for user "user1.testnet.com"
2022-04-30 15:17:27.036 CST [29520] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 79: "hostssl all all all cert map=mymap"
```

What was wrong?

Comment: That mapping should let you log in as "user1".  But apparently you are asking to log in as "user1.testnet.com".  Those are not the same.  Assuming the real username you want to log in as is "user1", then the problem is in your client not correctly specifying its intention, not in your mapping.

Comment: @jjanes If I understood correctly, the user map only maps the `CN` part to a valid user. So that a certificate with `CN=user1.testnet.com` can login as `user1` (it should normally be `CN=user1`

Comment: Yes, that is what it does.  But you *asked* to log in as "user1.testnet.com", not as "user1".  The mapping file maps the cert CN, it doesn't map who it is you requested to log in as.  So your proven identity from the cert is "user1.testnet.com", who is allowed (via pg_ident) to log in as "user1", but you requested to log in as "user1.testnet.com".